# Angular Resolve: Variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with Angular Routes for the first time and I recently posed a question regarding a refresh losing some data, the answer I received was to use resolve. It seems to be the solution I was looking for however I cannot get it to work properly.

```js
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
           //determines redirects go via shortcuts, clicking on the management icon on the main page sends the routeProvider /MG which it then uses to pull the relevant HTML file
           $routeProvider
               .when('/MG', {
                   controller: 'teammateController',
                   templateUrl: './assets/departments/department.html',
                   resolve: {
                       activeDepartment: function() {
                           return 'Management'
                       }
                   }
               })
               .when('/PO', {
                   controller: 'teammateController',
                   templateUrl: './assets/departments/department.html',
                   resolve: {
                       activeDepartment: function() {
                           return 'Programs Office'
                       }
                   }
               })
               .when('/SM', {
                   controller: 'teammateController',
                   templateUrl: './assets/departments/department.html',
                   resolve: {
                       activeDepartment: function() {
                           return 'Sales And Marketing'
                       }
                   }
               })
               .when('/', {
                   controller: 'teammateController',
                   templateUrl: 'home.html',
                   resolve: {
                       activeDepartment: function() {
                           console.log("working");
                           return 'home';
                       }
                   }
               })
               .otherwise({
                   controller: 'teammateController',
                   templateUrl: 'home.html',
                   resolve: {
                       activeDepartment: function() {
                           console.log("working");
                           return 'home';
                       }
                   }
               })
       }]);

   app.controller('teammateController', function teammateController($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, Idle, $location) {
       $scope.deptName = activeDepartment();
     });
```

I receive "ReferenceError: activeDepartment is not defined". The console log works and I see "working", so I know resolve is being run but, then the error message appears. I've tried everything I can think of and I cannot for the life of me see where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your controller needs a local injection. This means that when the controller is instantiated you need to provide the resolved data for the controller, just like you provide `$scope` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolved properties are injected into your controller, so try this:

```
app.controller('teammateController', function teammateController($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, Idle, $location, activeDepartment) {
   $scope.deptName = activeDepartment;
 });
```

*Notice the additional argument at the end of your controller.*

Comment: I tried that earlier but it gave me another error "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: activeDepartmentProvider <- activeDepartment <- teammateController" Which I also cannot figure out, do I need it in my dependencies as well?

Comment: @ColtonWilliams You don't need to add any additional dependencies, above should be sufficient. The error message indicate that your resolved property doesn't get injected properly, and therefor angular is looking for a provider called activeDeparment.

Comment: @ColtonWilliams I never use ngRoute myself, so I'm not sure, but according to [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) `For easier access to the resolved dependencies from the template, the resolve map will be available on the scope of the route, under $resolve` so perhaps you could try `$scope.$resolve.activeDeparment` as well. Just a guess though...

Comment: Good idea, I missed that in the docs, they also have an example that seems to be doing what I am looking for. I guess I will just scrap what I have and start over. I think part of the problem is that I am trying to add in routes after my whole app is built instead of including them from the beginning and I just don't have the skills to make it work. Thank again though I think you and @Amy got me on the right track.

Comment: GOT IT!!!! Not sure if this is the most efficient/proper way to do it since it kinda feels like a work around but `$scope.deptName = $route.current.locals.departmentName;` gets it, weird thing is that it doesn't need (at least in this instance) to be injected into the controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.controller('teammateController', function teammateController($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, Idle, $location) {
       $scope.deptName = activeDepartment();
     });
```

should be

```
app.controller('teammateController', function teammateController($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, Idle, $location, activeDepartment) {
       $scope.deptName = activeDepartment;
     });
```

BTW, the syntax you're using is not going to work if you want to minify your code.

Comment: I don't believe I want to minify it, but could you explain why? For future reference?

Comment: It will work if you use ngAnnotate before you minify the code: https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate

Comment: The minifier will take your variable names and change them to things like n, u, v. When Angular goes to look for n, u, or v in the injector, it won't find anything, because it was actually registered as $scope, $http, $rootScope, etc. There's plenty of documentation available on this issue and the other alternate syntaxes you could use.

Comment: Thanks @Amy that makes sense.