# Passing parameters through routeProvider resolve on AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm fairly new to Angular, and right now I'm following a tutorial where they create an app with user authorization levels. So I have built up the service, and I'm trying to pass a permissions parameter on routeProvider app config, but it throws me an error.

This is my code:

```
var ngApp = angular.module('neoAutr', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'md.data.table', 'LocalStorageModule', 'angular-loading-bar'])
//Permisos de App
.constant('APP_PERMISSIONS', {
    viewHome: "viewHome",
    viewInversions: "viewInversions",
    viewChecks: "viewChecks",
    viewLibrary: "viewLibrary",
    viewOverdrafts: "viewOverdrafts",
    viewOperations: "viewOperations",
    enableUserLevel: "enableUserLevel",
    enableIgnore: "enableIgnore"
})
//Servicio de ruteamiento
.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/views/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        }).
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController',
            review: {
                    permissions: [APP_PERMISSIONS.viewHome]
            }
        }).
        when('/cheque', {
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/views/cheque.html',
            controller: 'chequeController',
        }).
        when('/info', {
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/views/info.html',
            controller: 'infoController'
        }).
        when('/operations', {
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/views/operations.html',
            controller: 'operationsController'
        }).
        when('/inversions', {
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/views/inversions.html',
            controller: 'inversionsController'
        }).
        when('/overdrafts', {
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/views/overdrafts.html',
            controller: 'overdraftsController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
  }]);
```

I get on console the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

Anyone could enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT** Here are the libraries I'm calling on the head on index.html, hope this could help enlighten this issue

```
<!-- Angular -->
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/loading-bar.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/loading-bar.css" />

    <!-- Angular Material -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/md-data-table.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/md-data-table.min.js"></script>

    <!-- App-->
    <script src="Scripts/app/config.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems you are missing a library. Could you post your HTML declaration where you are referencing the JS files/libraries?

Comment: @Batuta question edited including my script calls

Comment: Which module is giving you an error? It should provide a complete link in your chrome console. Also, try to play around by removing one module in this declaration: ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'md.data.table', 'LocalStorageModule', 'angular-loading-bar'] and running your application. That way, you could point out which module is causing you the error.

Comment: @Batuta I will test that, I did not knew Angular parsed errors that way, well on the link it said this: `Failed to instantiate module neoAutr due to:
ReferenceError: APP_PERMISSIONS is not defined`

Comment: @Batuta seems odd, I declared APP_PERMISSIONS as a constant on the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
permissions: [APP_PERMISSIONS.viewHome]
```

to

```
permissions: ['APP_PERMISSIONS', function(APP_PERMISSIONS) {
   return APP_PERMISSIONS.viewHome;
}]
```

The resolve value has to be a function that returns whatever you want injected. The syntax I used will also minify if you are going to minify your code.

Note that I'm requesting that the constant be injected into the resolve function, not the module route configuration function.

Comment: This approach allows me to invoke the permissions parameter on app.run? Or how could I do that, basically I'm including the parameter there to access it before loading views

Comment: This doesn't change when the permissions are loaded, it just allows you to actually receive the value into the controller.

Comment: For more information on how this works, see this near-duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003106/angular-resolve-variable-is-not-defined/35003183#35003183

Comment: Thank you for the link, it seems quite easy, just a last clarification, how is this different from injecting into the function?

Comment: It is injecting it into the function that needs it, not some other function that can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject `APP_PERMISSIONS` into your `config` service like this:

```
    config(['$routeProvider','APP_PERMISSIONS',
      function ($routeProvider, APP_PERMISSIONS) {
       $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/views/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        }).
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController',
            review: {
                    permissions: [APP_PERMISSIONS.viewHome]
            }
        }).
```

Here is a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/lloB0WfnqPe2kVGb0otF?p=preview) hope this help!

Comment: For this to work, APP_PERMISSIONS.viewHome would need to be a function.

Comment: the issue is about the injection error, and this should resolve that! find the link above

Comment: How is that a working example? Your controller isn't accessing the value that isn't being resolved, so you don't know that it isn't being resolved.